# How do I do multiple sets in a transaction?

Tags: angular, firebase, transactions, google-cloud-firestore

I’m trying to run a transaction in my firebase/angular 6 application and it’s not working.

Here’s what I have:

```js
try {
  const transactionResult = await db.runTransaction(async trans => {

  let groupRecords: any[] = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < groupIDs.length; i++) {
    const groupDocRef = db.collection('Groups').doc(groupIDs[i]);
    const groupDoc = await trans.get(groupDocRef);
    groupRecords.push(groupDoc);
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < groupRecords.length; i++) {
    const groupData = groupRecords[i].data();
    await trans.set(groupRecords[i].ref, groupData, {merge: true});
  };

  return trans.commit();
} catch (err) {
  console.log('Error updating groups:', err);

  return Promise.reject('Error updating groups: ' + err);
}

return trans.commit();
```

The problem I’m having is that this transaction keeps repeating (based on console logs I omitted in the above code snippet) and then throws an error: The referenced transaction has expired or is no longer valid.

Normally, when I do a transaction, I return the results of trans.set(…) and that works. This time I can’t do that. This time, I’m updating a set of groups. I do all my gets first (in the first for loop) and then I do all my sets (in the second for loop). I don’t return these sets as I want the for loop to complete for all of them. The only thing I can think of once the sets are done is to do a commit. Hence: `return trans.commit()`. <— But that seems to result in the repeated runs of the transaction culminating in the error.

How does one return the appropriate object in a transaction such that the transaction works (i.e. doesn’t repeat, doesn’t throw expired/invalid error, is able to roll back if something goes wrong, etc.) when one had to do multiple sets?

Comment: The code you've copied and pasted doesn't look correct because the `runTransaction` function doesn't close. Should it close before or after the `return trans.commit();`?

Comment: Yes, it should. My bad. And you can ignore the last return trans.commit() as well.